# What is the biggest font by percentage of CJK symbols already encoded?

Tags: fonts

Only the Unicode-included Unified and six extensions considered for the question (87887 symbols, 12 compatibility included).

Possible contenders:

BabelStone Han: includes all of original map and partially all the extensions.

Source/Noto: includes all possible 65 535 physical TrueType-includable symbols, but also incomplete outside the original map.

MingLiU: circumvents the problem by having multiple files and covers all B.

What is the biggest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hanazono](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/) is a good contender:

> U+4E00  .. U+9FA5  URO 20,902 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+9FA6  .. U+9FEA  URO addition 69 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+3400  .. U+4DB5  Ext-A 6,582 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+20000 .. U+2A6D6 Ext.B 42,711 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+2A700 .. U+2B734 Ext.C 4,149 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+2B740 .. U+2B81D Ext.D 222 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+2B820 .. U+2CEA1 Ext.E 5,762 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+2CEB0 .. U+2EBE0 Ext.F 7,473 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+F900  .. U+FAD9  CJK Compatibility Ideographs 472 chars (fully implemented)
>   U+2F800 .. U+2FA1D CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement 542 chars (fully
>                      implemented)
>   IVD .. (version 2016-08-15) 28,770 chars (8,828 variants included)
>   (fully implemented)

Another good option would be [天珩](http://zisea.com/download/)

> CJK基本区     [4E00-9FEA] 20971字
>   CJK扩展A  [3400-4DB5] 6582字
>   CJK扩展B  [20000-2A6D6] 42711字
>   CJK扩展C  [2A700-2B734] 4149字
>   CJK扩展D  [2B740-2B81D] 222字(原先扩展D废除一字，字库中放于2A6FF，非标准码位请勿乱用)
>   CJK扩展E  [2B820-2CEA1] 5762字
>   CJK扩展F  [2CEB0-2EBE0]7473字
>   CJK兼容   [F900-FAFF] 512码位实际472字
>   CJK兼容扩展     [2F800-2FA1F] 544码位　实际542字

---

[Babel Stone](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) only claims:

> 53.3%

coverage with their Babel Han font.

Comment: Hmm, hard to beat 100% coverage :)